# Send Email to user who enters his id automatically

Tags: android

Please help

When user enters his email and hits the button then an email should be sent to him whose format is predefined and he enters into next activity. How to do this task.

Comment: What email are you using? Any languages related to it? Can you provide more information please?

Comment: Thanks for replying

Comment: Sir you must have seen in most of the apps when we enter our email id in registeration form and click on register button. We get an email from that particular app like Thanks for joining us and many more like that. I want to do this task in my android app i.e when user enters his email id and hit register button at that moment email should be sent to him written - "thanks for joining us -". I am not able to do this work please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have a edit text where the user enters his email id:

```
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { contactEmail.getText().toString() }); // change the Id of the edit text with what you have
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, ""));
```

Comment: Sir you must have seen in most of the apps when we enter our email id in registration form and click on register button. We get an email from that particular app like Thanks for joining us and many more like that. I want to do this task in my android app i.e when user enters his email id and hit register button at that moment email should be sent to him written - "thanks for joining us -". I am not able to do this work please help.